# Validating an iOS app

Tags: iphone, ipad, validation, certificate

We have an iOS app which interacts with various webservices at the backend. The backend however wants to validate that the request coming to it is from our valid iOS app and not from a replay attack or a "man in the middle" attack. We are eventually going to have all our calls changed to https. However, is there any way the backend can validate the request is coming from our legitimate app? We were thinking of using cryptographic nonce with every request, but it would still be prone to "man in the middle" attack. Is there any certificate exchange that can be used between the iOS app and the server?

Answer (score 3):

what about using a private/public key scheme so that the iOS app can sign every request it sends?

if private/public key scheme may sound scary, the same idea of "signing" your requests can be easily implemented by hashing your crypto nonce by using [sha1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1), [sha2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) or other cryptographic hashing algorithms. this would be pretty easy to implement (implementation are readily available), fast, and would ensure a higher security level.

Answer (score 3):

TLS and SSL support [client authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake) using certificates. NSStream *might* support client side authentication, but I have not been able to find a way to do it without dropping down to using OpenSSL for the actual implementation.

Addition:
[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) supports [client certificates](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#client_certificates) since version 1.8, so no fuss in implementing it.

Comment: I implemented (probably in a half-broken manner) this for a school [project](https://github.com/paxswill/SecureGateway) last semester. The main parts of interest would be the [PXConnection](https://github.com/paxswill/SecureGateway/blob/master/SStore/Source/PXConnection.h) and [PXClient](https://github.com/paxswill/SecureGateway/blob/master/AppGate/Source/PXClient.m) classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use OAuth. It well known and understood and pretty much secure, and in the case that someone gets your token, you can issue a new one with an app update and revoke the old one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general http problem, not just an iOS issue. In fact, it's the very problem https is designed to solve, or at least mitigate. You can sign the request, use HMAC to authenticate the message, use digest authentication, and so on, but as long as you're using http, a man-in-the-middle attack cannot be easily detected. Spend your time moving to https as quickly as you can instead.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is impossible to solve absolutely. Anything you put into your scheme can be ultimately broken by jailbreaking the phone and running the client in a debugger. Of course, that doesn't mean you can't make it more difficult to spoof your client using client certificates and whatnot, and you should. But if for example the security of financial transactions depend on your app not being spoofable, that would be bad...